# Задержка в активации плагинов/виджетов. Вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

При активации/деактивации плагина или виджета есть сообщение об успешном выполнении,но результат появляется только через некоторое время (несколько минут).

Чем может быть вызвана эта задержка?

Comment: Не до конца понял когда появляется сообщение(после нескольких переходов в панели администрирования, илb сама же активация или деактивация плагинов осуществляется долгое время).
Скорее всего, у вас недостаточно ресурсов, поетому и процес занимает долгое время, попробейте поднять `php_memory_limit`.

Comment: Сама активация/деактивация происходила долго. php_memory_limit 256M. Пытаюсь отловить проблему, сейчас нет задержки, но периодически замечаю её. Спасибо за отклик, увеличу еще лимит...

Comment: Также проверь  `cron` , и советую отключить проверку обновлений, тоесть оставить ее только если администатор вручную нажмет проверку.

Comment: Да у меня глючил   `wp_cron`, почему-то слетала дата в вордпрессе ( вперед) , и все задания запланировались на несколько месяцев вперед, менял в ручную задания через WP Crontrol. Спасибо за совет по отключению обновлений, и постараюсь все нужные задачи повесить на серверный крон